# Can you use Espresso if you don't have access to code?

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso, ui-automation, android-espresso-recorder

I don't know if I understood correctly, but you can test with Espresso just if you have access to the app code?

Answer (score 0):

Here You find a comprehensive answer about using espresso without source code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327515/10604486