# Automating Performance Testing in Espresso without source code

Tags: android, automation, performance-testing

I am new about Android and UI Testing,so I learn something [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-perf-testing/#0).

But,I want to measure app performance without source code.

Is it not possible to automation android app using espresso without source code?

Like here says:

[Automation of Android APK with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393159/automation-of-android-apk-with-espresso)

Maybe there has some solution to use espresso with just apk?

[What are list of tasks thats ConnectedAndroidTest executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713525/what-are-list-of-tasks-thats-connectedandroidtest-executes)
could this link solve my question?

or there have other android-sdk testing tools that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cant use Espresso without the source code. What you can do is to use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html).

Comment: By using UIAutomator, can I automate performance testing?

Could I just replace Espresso of [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-perf-testing/#0) ?

Do you have same samples or suggestion might help me learn UIAutomator more effectively and  do what I want to do?
Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to emulate clicks, it can sometimes replace espresso. if you want to do the thing with the GlobalTimeout, I am not sure it is possible. But give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try some tools like:

- AT&T ARO http://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer
  (you can run automated or manual test by capturing data using ARO)
- Monkop: https://www.monkop.com (upload espresso tests or just use Robo-Test)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run performance testing using Espresso without source code.

Refer [AndroidTestWithoutSource](https://github.com/cmoaciopm/AndroidTestWithoutSource)