# Can I launch an existing app using espresso instrumentation test?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I want to open the existing app and then navigate to my app. is this possible using the espresso test?
Note: The existing app(pre-installed) is independent and I don't have its source code or any control over it. I know the main activity of the existing app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automation of Android APK with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393159/automation-of-android-apk-with-espresso)

Comment: Thanks, @paulsm4 for sharing the info, unfortunately it did not help me case

Comment: You *can*, in theory, build Espresso tests without having Android source.  [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327595/421195) discusses how. 
 Personally, I'd recommend trying [Appium](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/appium-tutorial-for-testing). 
 Look here: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/appium-vs-espresso